# xlwings or VBA works on Windows 10 but not mac (Python)

Tags: python, xlwings

I have the following part of code that breaks:

```
for sheet in all_sheet_names:
if sheet.name != "Products":
    sheet.range("A1").value = "Attribute Name"
    sheet.range("B1").value = "Attribute Value"
    sheet.range("D1").value = "Description (only for non existing attributes!)"
    sheet.range("E1").value = "Unit (only for non existing attributes!)"
    sheet.range("C1").value = "Name (only for non existing attributes!)"
    for cell in list(range(2, 11)):
        cell_number = "C" + str(cell)
        print(cell_number)
        Formula1 = "File Upload,Text,Number,Number with units, Multiple choice, Radio button, Bolean"
        sheet.range(cell_number).api.Validation.Add(Type=3, Formula1=Formula1)
    for cell in list(range(2, 11)):
        cell_number = "E" + str(cell)
        Formula1 = "mm,kPa,N,m,m2,t,C,cm,W/mK,mm/mK,dB,MN/m3,kg/m3,m2K/W,kJ"
        sheet.range(cell_number).api.Validation.Add(Type=3, Formula1=Formula1)
```

The broken section, also seen from the screenshot is on line 43 and 47 this api.Validation.Add().

This is the link to the documentation for Validation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add

On Windows 10 this code runs perfectly fine with no error, the problem is on mac.
Amy workarounds to this problem?
[image]

Comment: Do you actually have Office for Mac installed?  The `api` call needs to bring up the Excel application to run the VBA.  If you don't have Excel, then you can't run any VBA.

Comment: Check https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/934 i.e. the part where xlwings creator says _using `.api` is a workaround and platform dependent. You seem to be on mac but using the syntax of the Windows library pywin32._ Being platform dependent it looks the code that works on windows shall not work on mac

Comment: Hi, yeah I have the latest version of Excel installed.

Comment: Thanks I will check the link! I will have to think of a workaround.

Comment: See also https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html